AzCopy log file - MD5 mismatch
I'm using AzCopy --check-md5  while downloading files from storage account.
However, I case of Md5 mismatch, how can I check this in the azcopy.log file? How is the Md5 mismatch error logged in the azcopy.log file(AzcopyVersion  10.17.0)?
If anyone can provide how the log entries look for a MD5 mismatch then that would be helpful

Most likely, the log would contain something like this:

[ERROR] <SOURCE_BLOB>: The MD5 hash calculated from the
downloaded data does not match the MD5 hash stored in the property of
source: <SOURCE_BLOB>. Please refer to help or documentation for
detail.

At least, this error is mentioned in this (admittedly old) issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/124 ; and in this (even older) SO question: AZCopy - MD5 calculated and MD5 in property always miss matching?

Will this come under DOWNLOADFAILED category in the azcopy logs? AzCopy has 3 categories - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-configure#log-and-plan-files So I assume Md5 mismatch will come under download failed? I'm re-running all the files from download failed.

@ZenoGh I would also assume so as it is about the "downloaded data"
